# flutter text, prevent automatically breaking lines when it has space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I realized that it automatically brake lines
and I want to prevent this

```
                                 Expanded(
                                  child: RichText(
                                    text: TextSpan(
                                      text: 'Hello', // default text style
                                      children: <TextSpan>[
                                        TextSpan(
                                            text: ' beautiful ',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                                fontStyle:
                                                    FontStyle.italic)),
                                        TextSpan(
                                            text: 'dddddddddddddddddddd ddddddddddddddddddddddd',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.bold)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
```

it has a space between ddddd and ddddd
so it automatically break lines

the Text widget automatically makes some blank

when next word is too long then make a new line

but I do not want to

is there any solution for this?

Comment: I think we need more UI context to help you with this

Comment: @encubos its very common thing I guess you can try your own, everywhere I guess. the Text widget automatically makes some blank when next word is too long then make a new line

Answer (score 6):

softWrap:false in RichText, it helps but you did not see the whole text
maxLines is also a paramter
you can take a look at the package auto_size_text
https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

```
                  new Expanded(
                      child: RichText(
                        //maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'Hello', // default text style
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: ' beautiful ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontStyle:
                                    FontStyle.italic)),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'dddddddddddddddddddd ddddddddddddddddddddddd',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight:
                                    FontWeight.bold)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: if i wrap expanded into a row, it works.. what is your code before expanded?

Comment: I tried it in a row but it never make new line then. I just want a new line when the text arrived at end. the my problem is every text Widget automatically makes new line when the next word is too long for including just one line